# Providing Support for Facebook Login in AWS Cognito

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, facebook-login

We want to build support for Login with Facebook for our application, which uses AWS Cognito.

We want to make use of our corporate mail ID for creating the FaceBook account.

But looks like at the time of creating a FaceBook account, we need to provide the name of some user (First Name and Last Name)

We observed that while creating the new account, Facebook accepts the corporate mail ID but it requires First Name and Last name.

We don’t want to tie up this account to a specific User.

Is there anything like a corporate Facebook account?

Any pointers/links  will be helpful.

Comment: No, there is not. Anyone who wants to develop on the platform, needs to use their personal account to do so. (You can add multiple users as admin of your app though, if losing access when someone leaves the company or similar is a concern.)